# « Si vous l'aimez mieux »

Tags: sens, expressions, france

Il est courant de dire ou d'écrire en français moderne « si vous aimez mieux ». On trouve chez George Sand un tour qui doit sans aucun doute signifier la même chose, et qui diffère par l'ajout du pronom « le ».

> Mais il y avait une telle idée sur le compte de la mère Fadet, que certains, et notamment
> ceux du père Barbeau, s'imaginaient que le grelet et le sauteriot, ou, si vous l'aimez  mieux, le grillon et la sauterelle, leur porteraient malheur s'ils faisaient amitié avec eux.

Le remplacement de « le » dans la phrase serait «  le grillon et la sauterelle », et donc il n'y a pas d'erreur de grammaire. Cette possibilité alternative pourrait donc être utilisée.

Est-ce que la variante que Sand utilise donne une impression de vieille langue de nos jours ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Est-ce que la variante que Sand utilise donne une impression de vieille langue de nos jours ?

Ça dépend à qui on demande. Pour un jeune d'aujourd'hui, « si vous aimez mieux » avec ou sans « l' », l'intégralité de *La petite Fadette*, toute la littérature du XIXè siecle et probablement une immense partie de celle du XXè donne sans doute une impression de vieille langue.

Concernant « si vous l'aimez mieux », je ne dirais pas que c'est l'indice le plus important d'une langue desuète dans ce passage. Un auteur contemporain pourrait tout à fait utiliser cette variante dans un style fantasque ou poétique ou pour faire passer le narrateur pour ampoulé, obséquieux plus que vieillot.

« Il y avait une idée sur le compte de », « faire amitié avec » me semblent ici davantage accuser leur époque.

Comment: Quel serait l'équivalent « jeune » de « si vous (l') aimez » ?

Comment: « si tu veux », « si tu préfères » ?

Comment: Je connais ceux-là, bien sûr, et ils sont si usuels que je n'y pensais pas ; ces expressions sembleraient représenter une meilleure appréhension du concept, elles sembleraient apporter un progrès. Merci de prendre la peine d'ajouter ces deux détails.